# Docker ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /home/sam/code/docker/.env.dev

Tags: django, docker

I'm learning how to use docker with Django. So first step is you setup the `Dockerfile` and here's the content of the file.

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

another file the `docker-compose.yml` file content below

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./project
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
```

now these two files are in the folder `docker` which also has my django project folder called `project` keeping it simple :)

When I run `docker-compose build` I get back the error

```
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /home/sam/code/docker/.env.dev
```

Comment: Where is the `.env.dev` file being copied?

Comment: was getting same error I know you possibly solved it but if someone else come then check that your `env` file does not have any spaces in the name mine was `.env.dev ` the last space in the name was making it a different file name

Answer (score 11):

You are specifying that .env file can be found in the location where your docker-compose.yml file is located.

```
env_file:
  - ./.env.dev
```

Make sure that your .env file is available there. If you don't need any environment variables to be set just remove above line from the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: found a tutorial that explains more on the good side also this works

Comment: care to share this tutorial?